# Meaning of "on the breast of the flood"

Tags: meaning

> The boat dipped and swayed and sometimes took on water, but it did not sink; the two brothers had waterproofed it well. I do not know where it finally fetched up, if ever it did; perhaps it reached the sea and sails there forever, like a magic boat in a fairytale. All I know is that it was still afloat and still running **on the breast of** the flood when it passed the incorporated town limits of Derry, Maine, and there it passes out of this tale forever.
> It by Stephen King.

Could you please tell me if "on breast of the" means "in the center of"?

Comment: Have you looked up the word "breast" to see if any meanings there fit the context?